# Lambda with empty capture list still able to capture objects from global scope?

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

I have a couple global static objects. Never mind that these are Qt classes, that's irrelevant to the matter.

```
static const QStringList JpegFileExtensions = QString::fromLatin1(jpegExtensions).split(" ");
static const QStringList TiffFileExtensions = QString::fromLatin1(tiffExtensions).split(" ");
static const QStringList RawFileExtensions = QString::fromLatin1(rawExtensions).split(" ");
static const QStringList PngFileExtensions = QString::fromLatin1(pngExtensions).split(" ");
```

Now, I have another static object that's initialized by some function that takes the previous objects and computes the result:

```
inline QString GetAllSupportedExtensions() {
   QStringList extensions = QStringList() << JpegFileExtensions << TiffFileExtensions << RawFileExtensions << PngFileExtensions;
   for (QString& item: extensions)
        item.remove("*.");

   return extensions;
}

static const QString AllSupportedExtensions = GetAllSupportedExtensions();
```

But since this `GetAllSupportedExtensions` function is not used anywhere else, I wanted to get rid of it so that it doesn't clutter the namespace. Naturally, I thought of using a lambda, it being an anonymous function:

```
static const QStringList AllSupportedExtensions = []() -> QStringList {
    QStringList list = QStringList() << JpegFileExtensions << TiffFileExtensions << RawFileExtensions << PngFileExtensions;
    for (QString& item: list)
        item.remove("*.");

    return list;
} ();
```

Note the empty capture list and empty list of arguments. It compiles and works on Windows (msvc-2013) and OS X (clang-700.1.81). How so? Is it standard-compliant, should it even compile with an empty capture list?

Comment: Can you make a [mcve], removing the Qt dependency and providing a `main()`?

Comment: @YSC: Sure. Hold on.

Comment: Ho, never mind, look at NathanOliver's answer. It's that simple.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The lambda is not capturing anything.  You are using global variables in a function.  The function body of a lambda is what is put inside `operator()` of an unnamed class that represents the lambda.  You can do this with any function.

You can see this working with this simple example

```
int i = 10;

class Foo
{
public:
    void operator()() { i = 20; }
};

int main(){

    Foo f;
    f();
    std::cout << i;
}
```

<kbd>[Live Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e69e32afe15c459e)</kbd>

Comment: I see, thank you. It's obvious that it would work with a regular class, I just wasn't sure about a lambda.

Comment: @VioletGiraffe A lambda is a class.  From [expr.prim.lambda]: *The type of the lambda-expression (which is also the type of the closure object) is a unique, unnamed nonunion
class type*