# Accessing variables in lambda without capture list

Tags: c++, list, variables, lambda, capture

I wonder why I can use global variables (thanks to Chris Drew for correcting me) in lamdas and why I don't need to capture them:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

size_t i = 0;
vector<int> v = {1,2,3};

int main()
{
    auto lambda = [](){i = v.size();};
    lambda();
    cout << i << endl;

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

In this minimum working example I am accessing the size_t and the vector without capturing them. I would have to if they were declared inside the main-method. Why is that so and how can I copy the size_t and the vector? I tried to use `[=]` as capture list but it does not copy `v` and `i`.

Comment: they are global variables

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Lambda with empty capture list still able to capture objects from global scope?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34398564/lambda-with-empty-capture-list-still-able-to-capture-objects-from-global-scope/34398671#34398671)

Comment: Please be more specific than "doesn't work". Post a program that "doesn't work" and explain what's wrong with it.

Comment: @ChrisDrew Terse humor is a spirit-lifter ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to capture a global variable by value is to use C++14 [generalized lambda captures](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/cpp14-language#lambda-captures):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

size_t i = 0;
std::vector<int> v = {1,2,3};

int main() {
    auto lambda = [myi = i, myv = v]()mutable{myi = myv.size();};
    lambda();
    std::cout << i << std::endl;
}
```

[Live demo.](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/KDTfnTHQ5j6rhcZs)

Answer (score 3):

Lambdas have accesses to global variables, and static variables in a class without explicitly capturing them. If it were a local variable, then you program would be ill-formed.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    size_t i = 0;
    vector<int> v = {1,2,3};
    auto lambda = [](){i = v.size();};   //Error, 
    lambda();
    cout << i << endl;

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

As seen [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/169e2659c03a70ec)

Same with static variables in a class:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

struct S{
    void touch(){ []{ k = 89; }(); }
    static int getK(){ return k; }
private:
    static int k;
};

int S::k = 0;


int main()
{
    S s;
    std::cout << S::getK() << std::endl;
    s.touch();
    std::cout << S::getK() << std::endl;
}
```

As seen [Here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/81155e4f0d54fcd7)

Comment: I know. I just used the wrong term to describe the vector and the size_t. I wonder how I can copy the size_t and the vector? Using `[=]` as capture list doesn't work.

Comment: If you capture a local variable and you need to modify the local capture, you need to use a `mutable` lambda

Comment: Using mutable seems to work when using local variables. But using it with global variables produces the original output.

Answer (score 2):

In your case `i` and `v` are global variable, accessible to the whole TU.

As you asked how to capture them by value, I think you should be able to capture them using both `[=]` or listing the variables `[i, v]`, but this would lead to an error, because they will be read-only and you are assigning to `i` inside the lambda body.

**Option 1:**
capture i by ref and v by value (if that makes sense at all...):

```
#include <iostream>  
#include <vector>  
using namespace std;
int main() {
    size_t i = 0;
    vector<int> v = {1,2,3};
    auto lambda = [&i,v](){i = v.size();};
    lambda();
    cout << i << endl;

    return EXIT_SUCCESS; }
```

http://ideone.com/fkn4za

**Option 2:**
use a mutable lambda and capture both by value (this makes even less sense).
I.e. [see this question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5501959/why-does-c0xs-lambda-require-mutable-keyword-for-capture-by-value-by-defau).
Please note that in this case also `i` will be captured by value, thus the global `i` will not be assigned, remaining at value == 0.

http://ideone.com/qwlFVv

Comment: And how can I copy it? Using `[=]` as capture list doesn't work

Comment: See my addition to the answer. It's not really clear why you want to capture them (both) by value.

Comment: I was expecting to see a zero getting printed because I don't operate on the global variables since I am trying to copy them.

Comment: As in option 2, if you capture i by value, the global i will not be assigned, remaining at value == 0.

Comment: That does not seem to work when using global variables.

Comment: Right, global variables are accessed directly anyway.

Comment: Any way to get that working? I mean copying the globals with the capture list. An obvious solution is to copy it with new variables though, but that is not what I intended.

Comment: Ok, I think I've found the reason why this is not possible.  
Explicitly capturing a global should be an error or UB, because §5.1.2/10 says:

"The identifiers in a capture-list are looked up using the usual rules for unqualified name lookup (3.4.1); each such lookup shall find a variable with automatic storage duration declared in the reaching scope of the local lambda expression."

Comment: There's also a more detailed answer on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9199744/gcc-incorrectly-captures-global-variables-by-reference-in-lambda-functions

Answer (score 2):

Your lambda is basically converted to a functor, it's the same as :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

size_t i = 0;
vector<int> v = {1,2,3};

struct lambda
{
  void operator()() { i = v.size(); }
};

int main()
{
    lambda x;
    x();
    cout << i << endl;

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

As you can see, `lambda` can perfectly access any global variable, it's even in their name, the variable is *globally* accessible.

If `i` and `v` were local to `main()` then we'd have an issue and we'd have to capture them.

Comment: Thanks, the core of my question, although I didn't express that very well, was to ask how I can copy the vector and the size_t. It seems like I should just copy them with a new size_t and vector.

Comment: @Bambino Yes, you can copy them inside the lambda and then work on those variables.